# Best Operations for Rails Database and Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This question is more about structure than technical, but anyone who has the technical advice is most welcomed to provide any assistance.

I am making a rails app that will help with a film project I am working on for locations.

The main entry will be Project. Each project will have many Script Locations (the setting in a film like a warehouse) that are only relevant to this Project. Each Script Location will have Locations (actual location of a real warehouse we find) these can be relevant to other projects as well so deleting them with a project would be bad. I would like the option to later down the road have the Locations be able to be assigned to other Script Locations for other Projects if they fit my needs. Now the question is how to best setup the data structures and routes for this.

So far I have come up with:

Project Model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :script_locations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Script Locations Model

```
class ScriptLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :locations
end
```

Location Model

```
class Location ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :script_location
end
```

Does this work the best? I am reading other posts and some suggest has_and_belongs_to_many while some say that is not a good way to go and other say has_many :through. I don't even know how that applies here. Additionally, I want to work with each Model with the CRUD and add more options later for other details. I am just sort of starting out and have some knowledge in rails but Im no expert. I had asked about another project earlier about triple nested, but I have read that is not good. So any suggestions on Routes would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :script_locations,dependent: :destroy
end
```

Script Locations Model

```
class ScriptLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :locations,  through: script_locations_locations
end
```

Location Model

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :script_locations,through: script_locations_locations
end
```

New Model(Many to many relation)

```
class ScriptLocationsLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :script_location
end
```

Now you can separately insert location and also you can insert it while inserting any script location also.
when you write a option in form whether you want to create new location or existing location. if you want to create new then at a time you will create a script location to script location table, a location to the location table and save their relation in the many to many table.

Comment: I only want to be able to add Locations separately. Script Location needs to be tied directly to Project as it is only ever associated with that Project. The Location is the only item that would float to other Script Locations. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you have still any confusion , ask me !

Comment: thank you. I would assume then the table migration would be t.references for each script_location and location?

Comment: create_table :script_locations_locations do |t|
      t.references :location, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :script_location, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end